# The margin of the nested element pushes the parent element instead of moving away from it

Tags: html, css

I don't understand why I am getting output like this. I was expecting the paragraph elements to be 100px away from all sides.

But I can see that it's not 100px away from the `main` element, at the top and bottom, instead, the `main` element moves itself by 100px down, which is not the case in the horizontal direction.

What is the reason for this?

```css
main {
  background-color: aqua;
  width: 50%;
}

p {
  background-color: #444;
  margin: 100px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p>This is <span class="opposite">another</span> paragraph.</p>
</main>
```

Comment: FYI, tags are just text in a file. You're talking about _elements_, which can have margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is called [Margin Collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing). You can read more by visiting the link. But here is an overview:

> The top and bottom margins of blocks are sometimes combined (collapsed) into a single margin whose size is the largest of the individual margins (or just one of them, if they are equal), a behavior known as margin collapsing.

It can happen in some well-known cases, but the one you are facing is this one:

> If there is no border, padding, inline part, block formatting context created, or clearance to separate the margin-top of a block from the margin-top of one or more of its descendant blocks; or no border, padding, inline content, height, or min-height to separate the margin-bottom of a block from the margin-bottom of one or more of its descendant blocks, then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.

And there are several workarounds. One is to set a padding on the parent:

```css
main {
  background-color: aqua;
  padding:1px; /* This padding fixes the callapsing of margin issue */
}

p {
  background-color: #444;
  margin: 100px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p>This is <span class="opposite">another</span> paragraph.</p>
</main>
```